# Linear Algebra proof relating to linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

1. Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$, and $T: V \to V$ a linear transformation.

(a) Show that $T^2=T$ iff $N(T)=\{x−Tx|x\in V\}$.

(b) If $T^2=T$, show that $V=N(T)+R(T)$.

I am not sure where to start for this proof because I am not sure exactly what it implies if $T^2=T$.

Comment: What are $N(T)$ and $R(T)$? The nullspace and range?

Comment: You should make a more serious effort. At least start by showing that $T(x-Tx)=0$. That shows $\{x-Tx\} \subset N(T)$. What do you need to show to see the reverse inclusion?

Comment: Well, $T^2 = T$ simply means that $T(T(x)) = T(x)$ for all $x\in V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note first that

$R(I - T) = \{x - Tx = (I - T)x, \; x \in V \}, \tag 1$

and

$T^2 = T \Longleftrightarrow T(I - T) = T - T^2 = 0. \tag 2$

For (a):

we have

$y \in N(T) \Longleftrightarrow Ty = 0 \Longleftrightarrow (I - T)y = y - Ty = y$ $\Longrightarrow y \in R(I - T)\Longrightarrow N(T) \subset R(I - T) ,\tag 3$

and

$y \in R(I - T) \Longleftrightarrow \exists z \in V, \; y = (I - T)z$
$\Longrightarrow Ty = T(I - T)z = (T - T^2)z = 0z = 0$
$\Longrightarrow y \in N(T) \Longrightarrow R(I - T) \subset N(T); \tag 4$

(4) and (5) together yield

$N(T) = R(I - T). \tag 5$

For (b):

$v = v - Tv + Tv = (I - T)v + Tv, \tag 6$

and

$T(I - T)v = (T - T^2)v = 0v = 0$
$\Longrightarrow (I - T)v \in N(T); \tag 7$

trivially,

$Tv \in R(T), \tag 8$

whence

$v \in N(T) + R(T); \tag 8$

we thus may write

$N(T) + R(T) \subset V \subset N(T) + R(T)$
$\Longleftrightarrow V = N(T) + R(T).  \tag 9$

We can actually take things one step further: if

$y \in N(T) \cap R(T), \tag{10}$

then

$Ty = 0, \tag{11}$

and

$y = Tz, \; z \in V; \tag{12}$

thus,

$y = Tz = T^2z = Ty = 0, \tag{13}$

which shows that

$N(T) \cap R(T) = \{0\}, \tag{14}$

and in fact we have

$V = N(T) \oplus R(T), \tag{15}$

the *direct sum* or $N(T)$ and $R(T)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since a) is suggested by these hints. So i shall prove b).

Let's show first,  $ N(T)\cap R(T)=\{0\}$.

To prove this,  let's assume $ T(v) \in N(T), T(v)\in R(T)$,  such that this $T(v) $ is non zero.  (Hence $v$ is not in $N(T)$....$(*)$). But see that by hypothesis,
$ T(T(v))=T^2(v)=0$ (since $ T(v)\in N(T)$).
But see that $N (T)=N (T^2)$,    so $T^2(v)=0\implies v\in N (T^2)= N(T)$, 
 and so contradiction to $(*)$.

Now,

$1)$.   $ N(T)\cap R(T)=\{0\}$.

$2.)$ $\dim N(T)+\dim R(T)= dim V$ (Rank- nulity theorem ).

$3.)$$N(T),  R(T)$ are the subspaces of $V$.

So now if $W=R(T)+ N(T)$ then $\dim W= \dim R(T)+\dim N(T)=\dim V $ and $W\subset V $.  So,  $W=V$. Proving the claim.